# how to add tabs to infowindow which uses extInfoWindows for google map

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, dhtml, infowindow

I have the following code to display the info window on the google map when marker is clicked how can i add tabs to the infowindows which is using extinfowindows ,can anyone help to trace out the problem.

```
function createMarker(point, name, address, imagepath) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point, gicons[imagepath]);
    var html1 = '<span class="name-tab"><b>' + name + '</b></span> <span class="info"><br/>' + address + '</span>';

    GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        marker.openExtInfoWindow(
        map, "simple_example_window", html1, {
            beakOffset: -4
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:tabs are not supported for GMaps v3.0

check this

> http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/02/working-with-info-windows-in-google-maps/

But we can make it for V3.0 using JQuery here is sample of code

```
    var contentString = [
  '<div id="tabs">',
  '<ul>',
    '<li><a href="#tab-1"><span>One</span></a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#tab-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#tab-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>',
  '</ul>',
  '<div id="tab-1">',
    '<p>Tab 1</p>',
  '</div>',
  '<div id="tab-2">',
   '<p>Tab 2</p>',
  '</div>',
  '<div id="tab-3">',
    '<p>Tab 3</p>',
  '</div>',
  '</div>'
].join('');

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

Comment: This is not working as intended but this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177705/google-maps-infowindow-not-showing-the-tabs-as-it-should fixes the issue :)