# Google maps infowindow not showing the tabs as it should

Tags: jquery, maps, infowindow

i had the info windows showing the tabs just fine a few weeks ago..
and now its not showing anymore...

In fact the code uses JQuery.. find the codes on this link http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/infowindow/tabs.html?r=78

I have included all the libraries of JQuery including the CSS files..
what is wrong?... 
what puzzles me is that it was working for quite a while and suddenly stopped..what actually happened??

Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: if there are links to other similar discussions on this forum please let me know..

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't figured it out yet, or for others that might be having the same issue...

It appears to be a timing issue.  $("#tabs").tabs() is being called prior to the tabs elements being created/visible/whatever.  Activate the tabs by adding an event listener to "domready" which is fired once the content is actually added to the DOM.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, but when i use jquery inside the domready handler, it doesn find the html tags i've added inside the infowindow. Any idea why and how could i make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Just a friendly "Thank You" to cdru
who supplied the solution above.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () { 
        $("#tabs").tabs();
```

This will fire the jQuery tabs method when the infoWindow is built !!!

Now, onto the next problem with sizing the infoWindow and removing the div scrollbars showing inside it.

Very nice, LA Guy

Comment: `Now, onto the next problem with sizing the infoWindow and removing the div scrollbars showing inside it.` There are 2 Css solutions: 1) overflow: hidden 2) adjusting the div height and width using % will remove the scrollbar.